# Laravel 5.4 many to many relationship query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I've tried to search for this problem, but don't know how to word it correctly.
So, I have 3 tables. 'breeds', 'breed_features' and pivot table 'breed_breed_feature'
I'm trying to get all breeds that have selected breed_features.
I'm passing breed_feature id-s to the controller from from in an array.
My relationships are correctly set, so I can get all $breed->features
and all $feature->breeds.

What have I tried:

```
$featureids = request('features');

$breeds = Breed::with('features')->whereHas('features', function($q) use ($featureids)
{
    $q->whereIn('breed_feature_id', $featureids);
})->get();
dd($breeds);
```

Result is all breeds that have atleast 1 of the feature id-s

```
$featureids = request('features');

$breeds = Breed::with('features')->whereHas('features', function($q) use ($featureids)
{
    $q->where('breed_feature_id', $featureids);
})->get();
dd($breeds);
```

Result returns all breeds that have features with first id in an array, query don't even try to pass rest of the id's.

```
$featureids = request('features');

$breeds = Breed::with('features')->whereHas('features', function($q) use ($featureids)
{
    foreach ($featureids as $f)
    {
        $q->where('breed_feature_id', $f);
    }
})->get();
dd($breeds);
```

Result return correct breeds if I pass only 1 id to query, if I pass more than 1, it always return empty collection.

Help please.

Comment: Option 3 is empty because you try to search an breed with `breed_feature_id` set to 1, 2, 3, 4 e.g. if you pass more than 1 but each breed only have 1 `breed_feature_id`.
About a year ago I had a similar problem and was able to solve it by using `whereHas` 3 times or using `reject`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I went totally other way around this problem. It works, but I'm pretty sure, that there must be a better way to do it.

```
 $features = BreedFeature::findMany(request('features'));
    $breeds = Breed::with('features')->wherehas('features')->get();
    foreach($features as $f)
    {
        $breeds = $breeds->intersect($f->breeds);
    }
```

So I fetch all the features from database by the ID-s from the form.
Then I fetch all the breeds from the database.
Then I will start intersecting $breeds collection with $feature->breeds.
Will test it more, but it seems to be working just fine right now.